# node-mysql returns column names instead of values

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I have a mysql query like this: `'SELECT ? FROM tablename'` with an args array like this: `['id']`. 
When I call `db.query(sql, args)` the result is an array with `['id', 'id', 'id']` for every row in the database table instead of having the values from the database in it `[1,2,3]`. 
If the column names are included in the sql string it works just fine. I really dont know why this happends. Is there someone else having issues like this and has a solution for it?

Comment: I dont know much about node but I doubt that you can parametrize column or table names

Comment: @Mihai `node-mysql` is actually nice in that you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parameterize column names with the `??` placeholder [as per the documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql):

```
db.query('SELECT ?? FROM tablename', [ [ 'id', 'id', ... ] ]);
```

Comment: Wow thats very simple and it solved the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Kilian - if this solved your issue consider indicating it as an accepted answer, good luck with your project!